# Get the list id from its url using REST?

Tags: sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-api

I'm using the SharePoint 2013 REST API to get and create list items, however the end users of my solution probably won't know how to find the list id, just the URL for one of its views, like http://spsportal/Lists/MyCalendar/calendar.aspx.

Is it possible to find the list ID using this URL?

Comment: DO you want to extract list name from the specified URL OR you want to get GUID of the specified list ?

Comment: I need to extract the GUID (list ID).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can see at least two options:

- [GetByTitle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn531433.aspx#bk_ListCollectionGetByTitle) REST method : The "MyCalendar" part of the url is the "simplified version" of the Title (meaning, if you had special characters, they'd be encoded).
  With a bit of Regex you should be able to extract the list name from the URL.
- [GetList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.getlist.aspx) /_api/web/GetList('/Lists/MyCalendar') The parameter has to be the server relative Url without the form information.

Just that you know, most of the methods available in SSOM are exposed on the REST API.

Comment: I've found this method, however if the list title changes, I think the URL would stay the same, but the GetByTitle won't be able to find it.

Comment: Gotcha, then you can use /_api/web/GetList('/Lists/MyCalendar'). The parameter has to be the server relative Url without the form information. Just that you know, most of the methods available in SSOM are exposed on the REST API https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.getlist.aspx

Comment: @baywet You should add your comment as a new answer because this really blew my mind as I was looking for something like this for a long time.

Comment: @andreas Thanks, I updated the answer, hopefully that helps other people as well. You can upvote now ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I can see at least three options:

- GetByTitle REST method : The "MyCalendar" part of the url is the "simplified version" of the Title (meaning, if you had special characters, they'd be encoded).
  With a bit of Regex you should be able to extract the list name from the URL.
- GetList /_api/web/GetList('/Lists/MyCalendar') The parameter has to be the server relative Url without the form information.
- getbyGUID : like this /_api/web/lists('%7B326038AE-D47E-454D-AAD4-5440E6133EF2%7D')